# Access Spring Web Acclication Context in Stateless EJB

Tags: spring, ejb, interceptor

at the moment we use Spring 4 and have a Java class loading all of our xml-config files:

- Root: Basic Framework
- Child: Project Application Services
- Child: Project Application Workflow
- Child: Framework Controller
- Child: CXF Webapplication Context

Every child knows the beans of it's parent and everythings works fine. Now I have to use an IBM EJB on an Websphere Application Server for communication with legacy systems. This EJB gets called and now I want to use our Spring Context to get some services.

The EJB is defined as

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "ejb/LegacyRocks")
@RemoteHome(com.ibm.websphere.ola.ExecuteHome.class)
public class WolaUseCaseOne {...}
```

I have alreade read about the SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor, but I do not get the point. I do not a a simple xml-file to get loaded, so can anybody provide me another way the autowire mit Spring Beans inside the EJB ?

PS:
I have also found this post (http://www.schakko.de/2013/10/11/sharing-the-spring-application-context-from-a-war-with-ejbs/), but we do not use JSF and it does not help me

I have already read, there is no way to inject the complete context, because we have a Webapplication Context, and there is not such a Web Context inside EJB...  ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create ejb as per following

```
@Local
public interface TestManager {

    boolean isValid();

} 

@Stateless(name = "java:global/TestManagerImpl", mappedName = "java:global/TestManagerImpl")
@EJB(name = "java:global/TestManagerImpl", beanInterface = TestManager.class)
public class TestManagerImpl implements TestManager {

    @PostConstruct
    public void ejbCreate() {

    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void ejbDestroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(){
        //your code
    }
}
```

and you need to implement spring service class with

```
@Service(value = "testServiceImpl")
public class TestServiceImpl {

    @EJB(name = "java:global/TestManagerImpl", mappedName = "java:global/TestManagerImpl")
    private TestManager testManager;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(){
      retrun testManager.isValid(); 
    }
}
```

**Edited**

call ejb to spring service method

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class TestManagerImpl implements TestManager {

    // automatically injected with a matching Spring bean
    @Autowired
    private TestService testService ;

    // for business method, delegate to POJO service impl.
    public String myFacadeMethod(...) {
        return testService.myMethod(...);
    }

    ...

}
```

Hope it work for you!!

Comment: Hi Ravi, thanks for the fast reply... As I see the code I think this is the way to inject an EJB into a Spring service, but I need it the other way round: I need to "inject" the Spring context into the EJB to find some services or autowire some beans...

Comment: @timo.gruetter i have update my answer so please check hope its work for you.